# Unable to install libpulse-dev

Tags: apt, raspbian-buster

I'am trying to install libpulse-dev with apt get install.
Somehow I am getting the following error code:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed

Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I don't know how to fix this error. Apt and dpkg do not list any brocken package.
My sources.list file:

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: Have you recently done an "sudo apt-get update"?  What version or Raspbian are you on? Perform `cat /etc/*release` and `uname -a`  My Pi already has `libglib2.0-dev` installed so I couldn't recreate this.  You could try to individually install the dependency using `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`

Comment: @HeatfanJohn the OP is using **buster** as you can see from his sources.list.

Comment: You can search libglib2.0-dev package online on [debian website](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libglib2.0-dev) and [download the package] (https://packages.debian.org/buster/armhf/libglib2.0-dev/download) manually for `armhf` architecture and then use `dpkg -i libglib2.0-dev.deb` , but maybe this lib need another libs , check the webpage before.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and post any error messages you encounter. The package `libglib2.0-dev` should be available in Raspbian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already had installed libglib2.0-dev package, but the installed version was too new for libpulse-dev.
The solution was to install libpulse-dev using aptitude. Aptitude did automatically downgrade libglib2.0-dev to the required version.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again months for months.